# Creating a general method to setResult from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two activities. Activity 1 starts Activity 2 which has a fragment which needs to call `setResult` in order to pass values back to Activity 1.

Currently I am doing this in the fragment code:

```
// FragmentClass.java
private final String EXTRA_VALUE_1_ID = "value_1";

private void setResult() {
    Intent data = new Intent();

    // value.getId() is of type UUID
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUE_1_ID, value.getId());
    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

However, now to retrieve the value in Activity 1, I have to either expose the extra key defined above or add another static method to the fragment as below:

```
// FragmentClass.java
public static UUID getValueId(Intent data) {
    return (UUID) data.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_VALUE_1_ID);
}
```

Which means I have to do something like this in Activity 1 class:

```
// Activity1.java
UUID id = FragmentClass.getValueId(data);
```

But this results in Activity 1 being coupled with FragmentClass. Is there a better solution to this? Since Activity 1 is already aware of Activity 2, I tried to move the `setResult` call to Activity 2. But I cannot figure out how to get the correct overridden implementation of `putExtra`. i.e. I tried something like:

```
// Activity2.java
public void setResult(ExtraKeys extraKey, Object value) {
    Intent data = new Intent();

    // Cannot resolve mothod 'putExtra(String, Object)'
    data.putExtra(extraKey.toString(), value);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

Is there a way to pass the type of value as well and then cast it accordingly? I'm new to Java and do not know enough about generics to work this out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use an `interface` for that. You can call a method in your fragment, pass the value to that method, and then implement the interface in your Activity 1.

```
 Fragment                             Activity 1
(call result(yourValue))           implement interface : result(int result)           
      |                                    |
      |----> Interface ------------------->|
             (method result(int result)
```

Create a new interface Communicator:

```
public interface Communicator {
   void result(Object result);
}
```

In your fragment :

```
Communicator comm;
...
comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
...
comm.result(yourValue);
```

In your Activity1 :

```
//make you class extend the interface (Communicator)
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator
...
//Override the method
@Override
public void result(Object result) {
  //result is you value, now you can do whatever you want with it

  result.getClass(); // this will return the type of object
  if(result.getClass().equals(Integer.class)){
    // do something
  }else if(...){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I use this method, I'll need to declare a new method in the interface for each type that of value that the fragment can set as a result?

Comment: No, it's way simpler,  just declare the parameter as an Object and then retrieve the type of that object in your Activity1. I edited my answer

Comment: I'll check and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: So the above solution gives a cleaner way to set the result from a fragment. However, this still doesn't help with the fetching of result within the original activity, which requires a key (given to putExtra) that I'd rather stays a private member of the fragment. Also, each time a new type is required to be set as a result, the activity implementing the result method would require a new `if` clause to handle that new type. Can I not get rid of the type checking if clause ladder somehow?

Comment: First I don't understand what key do you need, and what you mean by "fetching the result".. In Activity1, 'Object result' is the result you passed from the fragment.  About the type of object, it depends on what you need to do with it. If, for exemple, you just want to make a string of the result you won't need an if loop. But if you want to do different things according to the type of the result, then you will need an if statement.

Comment: OK so if statements aren't going anywhere.. :(
By 'key' I mean that the result once set by a fragment will be retrieved by another activity (Activity1 in this case, which starts Activity2, which in turn hosts the Fragment). Since the data is passed back activity (Activity1) as an Intent object, which itself has a hash like structure, a key is needed to get the data out of it. The data set by the fragment using a final string as a key.

Comment: If you told me more about what you want to do with the Object result, I could try to help, because right now I don't really understand the problem.
Also f you want to get te result in Activity 2, just implement the interface in there, you don't need to pass the result as an extra from Activity1 to Activity2, this is why interfaces are great.